# window.getSelection() is undefined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm making an extension for Firefox (opens a highlighted word's definition on Wiktionary in a new tab). I got stuck with the text select part: the recommended window.getSelection().toString() doesn't work as window.getSelection() is undefined.

Things I tried:

[JavaScript / jQuery: how to get selected text in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563045/javascript-jquery-how-to-get-selected-text-in-firefox) (also undefined)

[JavaScript / jQuery: get selection function not working in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538789/javascript-jquery-get-selection-function-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome) (neither of the branches works)

[window.getSelection() of textarea not working in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419515/window-getselection-of-textarea-not-working-in-firefox) (actually returns the string "undefined")

[window.getSelection returning undefined or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359605/window-getselection-returning-undefined-or-null) (only for chrome)

[Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) (either chrome only or undefined again)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and after quite some digging I found something that works:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('input_text_area');
var selectedText = textArea.value.substring(textArea.selectionStart,textArea.selectionEnd);
```

This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20427804/8758205) links to some background on why the above is necessary and why window.getSelection() doesn't work on Firefox, for example.